# how to get element type by name?

Tags: jquery

is there any elegant way to get element type by name?

I can expect rendered form contains dropdowns, inputs, tables, divs with name like "answer[x]" where x represent some number.
I need element type to know how to handle it.
I can try to get object with :

```
$('td[name=answer\\[1\\]]') 
$('div[name=answer\\[1\\]]')
$('input[name=answer\\[1\\]]')
```

and when `$('input[name=answer\\[x\\]]').length > 0` then "great! its input!".
It just doesn't look like elegant way...

Comment: is the element name `answer[1` ?

Comment: no, its my mistake.., <label id="answer_21_holder" class="answer_1">
<input id="answer_21" type="radio" value="21" name="answer[1]">
Very significant. Will affect the field
</label>

its **name="answer[1]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me `$("[name='answer[" + x + "]'")[0].tagName` is quite elegant :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this for **one element**:

```
$('[name=answer[1]')[0].tagName
```

Or this for **multiple elements**:

```
$('[name=answer]').each(function() {
    alert(this.tagName);
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eMhBg/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$tags = $('[name^=answer]'); // all element have name started with answer

$.each($tags, function() {
  console.log(this.tagName);
});
```

[Check it live](http://jsfiddle.net/TTcce/)